# Network to Subnet conversion

Tags: ip, subnet

How do you convert a network address such as 192.168.8.5 to a subnet address or get the default subnet mask for it? im very confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past classful subnets were used.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network for more information.  If you convert the address 192.168.8.5 to binary, it starts with 110, so it is a class C network.  Class C networks use a 24 bit subnet mask, i.e. 255.255.255.0.

Nowadays, classful networks are no longer used as the masks are inflexible and lead to a lot of wasted IPv4 addresses. We need to preserve IPv4 addresses by sizing networks appropriately.  CIDR replaced classful networks and allows the designer to allocate any size subnet mask to a network.  The only way to determine the subnet mask nowadays is to look at the design documents or check what mask has been entered on the interface configuration.